# Render only once a segment or partial in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to make complete blade components that contains the VueJs dependencies it needs

### Example

**views/shared/_manage-user-button.blade.php**

```
<button 
   @click.prevent="$modal.show('manage-user-modal', {
        url: '{{ route('users.update', $user) }}'
    })"
>
    Manage {{ $user->name }}
</button>


<manage-user-modal>
</manage-user-modal>
```

But every time I will re-call this component, the `<manage-user-modal>` will be re-rendered.

**A solution** would be to move `<manage-user-modal>` in the parent or globally, but it would break the idea of making partial independent.

### Start of a solution

```
@if(!isset($loop) ?: $loop->last)
    <manage-user-modal>
    </manage-user-modal>
@endif
```

With this, it works like a charm **BUT**, when the component is call in two different for-loop/places on the same page, it will still be rendered twice.

I also tried a "hacky" way

```
@if(config('manage-user-button-rendered')? false : config(['manage-user-button-rendered' => true]) )
    <manage-user-modal>
    </manage-user-modal>
@endif
```

But it seems to not be working on a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it was a stupid mistake...

`config(['manage-user-button-rendered' => true]` returns `null`
So I added `!` to returns `true`

[edit]
The most optimized way I found is to use `define` and I coupled it with a custom blade directive.

```
Blade::if('renderOnce', function ($key) {
            return defined($key)? false : define($key, true);
        });
```

And then

```
@renderOnce('manage-user-modal')
    <manage-user-modal>
    </manage-user-modal>
@endrenderOnce
```

[edit] Since Laravel 7 there is `@once` directive
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/33812

Comment: The ```@once``` tip did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would define the modal globally:

**index.blade**

```
<manage-user-modal>
    </manage-user-modal>
```

And to keep the partials independent, pass them the name of the modal as a variable:

**index.blade**

```
@include('partial',['user_modal' => 'manage-user-modal'])
```

**partial.blade**

```
<button 
   @click.prevent="$modal.show($user_modal, {
        url: '{{ route('users.update', $user) }}'
    })"
>
    Manage {{ $user->name }}
</button>
```

Comment: Having the modal in index.blade.php is how I alway did it. But as I said in the question, it would break the idea of making partial **fully** independent. The project I'm working on is getting bigger and bigger. Some places have that kind button in 2 partials deep. I have this kind of action almost everywhere. Some modal have props too.  More the time come, more it's getting difficult to remember why where and how. Using a partial like my example gives you every information it needs / uses at one place and makes it much more readable.

Comment: @cbaconnier think of it like dependency injection